# Automatically kill tmux session on session end?

Tags: ssh, tmux, bashrc

I have the following snippet in my .bashrc which starts tmux whenever I'm at the command line:

```
# Start inside tmux
if [[ $(command -v tmux) ]] && [[ -z $TMUX ]] && [[ $TERM != "screen" ]]; then
     exec tmux
fi
```

I often access this machine over `ssh`, and sometimes the pipe breaks for one reason or another (for example closing my laptop). When that happens, the tmux session continues to exist in detached state.

How can I automatically destroy such sessions?

Comment: Why not just start a session on first login and then just reattach to the tmux session if you disconnect and login again? `tmux a`

Comment: How would you do this programmatically? The output of `tmux list-sessions` seems impractical for use with a script.

Comment: In my `.bashrc` I have `if [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then tmux a || tmux; fi`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `destroy-unattached` tmux option:

```
destroy-unattached [on | off]

If enabled and the session is no longer attached to any clients, 
it is destroyed.
```